# Check that at least one of two input fields has data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields and I want to make sure that at least one of them is filled when a button is clicked.

```
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="first"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" id="second"><br>

<button type="submit" value="Submit">submit</button
```

How can this be done through jQuery? There is no form tag in the html code.

http://jsfiddle.net/zs7mau12/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the condition `$('#first').val() || $('#second').val()`, like this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', function () {
    if ($('#first').val() || $('#second').val()) { // will fail if both are ''
        alert("At least one has data");
    } else {
        alert("Oops! No data");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/6u1x8bmj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try like this:use `trim` to be safe from starting and ending or only spaces.

```js
 $('body').on('click', 'button', function () {
    if ($('#first').val().trim().length > 0 || $('#second').val().trim().length > 0) {
        alert("we have some data");
    } else {
        alert(" No data entered");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="first"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" id="second"><br>

<button type="submit" value="Submit">submit</button>
```